# Show the time an SMS was sent, not received

Tags: 2.2-froyo, samsung-galaxy-s, sms

Scenario is as follows-

- Switch flight mode on. Go into meeting/go to sleep.
- Switch flight mode off. Receive a message.
- Timestamp on the message is the time received.

With my old Nokia, under details it would show the time the message was actually sent. Is it possible to show this on Android?

Comment: It might depend on your messaging app -- HTC phones with Sense don't have the standard android mesages app, for example.  What phone do you have?

Comment: Ah, I hoped there wouldn't be a handset dependency. It's a Galaxy S.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an app called **SMS Timestamper** that appends the received time to incoming text messages. Worth mentioning for those not comfortable with fiddling with the OS's internals, or those unsure if it would work on their version of the firmware. I'm on JPO so I didn't want to chance it.

Answer (score 2):

It's a stupid setting of galaxy s sms' app. To resolve this you have to replace the mms.apk into /system/app with that attached in this thread of xda forum
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=891667&highlight=mod+sms
If you look all the thread, you can also find the complete installation guide!