# Show the original timestamp on received messages

Tags: sms, nexus-4

Is there any way I can change the message settings on my LG Nexus 4 to show the time a message was sent to my phone, rather than the time it was received?

Comment: [Show the time an SMS was sent, not received](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/4573) is 2 years old, but the answers might still be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

This was [raised as an issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2989) in June 2009 and despite being discussed extensively there doesn't appear to be any way to show the original timestamp in vanilla Android. This leaves you with a couple of options:

1. Use a custom ROM like CyanogenMod which supports this, or
2. Install an app like [SMS Sent Time](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=at.zweng.smssenttimefix&hl=en) which appends the message sent time to the message itself